# Driver-layer from top-level app to hardware

Tags: c++, object-oriented, inheritance, qt

I'm attempting to implement driver-layer (shared library) from top-level app to hardware.

In the first, I extracted interface functions, which further will be called from "extern "C" SHARED" wrappers to separate class `IDriverInterface`.

In the second, I want to hot-test some functions before the correct implementation and don't want to use `#define`, so I created a `QDriverInterfaceSim` class which inherits `QDriverInterface`.

Can anyone suggest any improvements on this?

**`IDriverInterface` class:**

```
#ifndef IDRIVERINTERFACE_H
#define IDRIVERINTERFACE_H

#include "types.h"

class IDriverInterface
{
public:
    virtual int connectToHardware() = 0;
    virtual int sendData(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz) = 0;
    virtual int sendDataWithAck(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, ack_id_t *p_ack_id) = 0;
    virtual int sendDataWithAckBlocked(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, timeout_t timeout_ms) = 0;
    virtual void reg_OnData_callback(onData_callback cb) = 0;
    virtual void reg_OnAck_callback(onAck_callback cb) = 0;
    virtual int addRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest, dev_addr_t next) = 0;
    virtual int removeRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest) = 0;
    virtual int getRouteTable(dev_addr_t dev, route_t route_table[1], rows_cnt_t *prow_count) = 0;
    virtual int setAutoRoute(dev_addr_t dev, bool en) = 0;
    virtual int ping(dev_addr_t dev, timeout_t timeout_ms) = 0;
};

#endif // IDRIVERINTERFACE_H
```

**`QDriverInterface` class:**

```
#ifndef QDRIVERINTERFACE_H
#define QDRIVERINTERFACE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qmyserialport.h"
#include "qserialportconfigdialog.h"
#include "qserialportinterface.h"
#include "idriverinterface.h"
#include "types.h"

class QDriverInterface : public QObject, public IDriverInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDriverInterface(QObject *parent = 0);

    // from IDriverInterface
    virtual int connectToHardware();
    virtual int sendData(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz);
    virtual int sendDataWithAck(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, ack_id_t *p_ack_id);
    virtual int sendDataWithAckBlocked(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, timeout_t timeout_ms);
    virtual void reg_OnData_callback(onData_callback cb);
    virtual void reg_OnAck_callback(onAck_callback cb);
    virtual int addRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest, dev_addr_t next);
    virtual int removeRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest);
    virtual int getRouteTable(dev_addr_t dev, route_t route_table[1], rows_cnt_t *prow_count);
    virtual int setAutoRoute(dev_addr_t dev, bool en);
    virtual int ping(dev_addr_t dev, timeout_t timeout_ms);

private slots:
    void setSerialParams();

protected:
    onData_callback m_onData;
    onAck_callback m_onAck;
    void debug_print(QString fun_name, QString msg = "");

private:
    void init();    
    void showConfigDialog();
    void sendTestPacket();

    QMySerialPort *m_serialPort;
    QSerialPortConfigDialog *m_serialConfigDialog;
    QSerialPortInterface *m_SerialPortInterface;
};

#endif // QDRIVERINTERFACE_H
```

**`QDriverInterfaceSim` class:**

```
#ifndef QDRIVERINTERFACESIM_H
#define QDRIVERINTERFACESIM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qdriverinterface.h"

class QDriverInterfaceSim : public QDriverInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDriverInterfaceSim(QObject *parent = 0);

    // from IDriverInterface
    //virtual int connectToHardware() { return 0;}
    virtual int sendData(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz);
    //virtual int sendDataWithAck(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, ack_id_t *p_ack_id) { return 0;}
    //virtual int sendDataWithAckBlocked(dev_addr_t dev, com_t com, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t data_sz, timeout_t timeout_ms) { return 0;}
    //virtual void reg_OnData_callback(onData_callback cb);
    //virtual void reg_OnAck_callback(onAck_callback cb);
    //virtual int addRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest, dev_addr_t next) { return 0;}
    //virtual int removeRouteRecord(dev_addr_t dev, dev_addr_t dest) { return 0;}
    //virtual int getRouteTable(dev_addr_t dev, route_t route_table[1], rows_cnt_t *prow_count) { return 0;}
    //virtual int setAutoRoute(dev_addr_t dev, bool en) { return 0;}
    //virtual int ping(dev_addr_t dev, timeout_t timeout_ms) { return 0;}

private slots:
    void callOnData();
    void callOnAck();

private:
    void setOnData(onData_callback cb, dev_addr_t *pdev, com_t *pcom, pdata_t pdata, data_sz_t *pdata_sz);

private:
    dev_addr_t *m_pdev;
    com_t *m_pcom;
    pdata_t m_pdata;
    data_sz_t *m_pdata_sz;
};

#endif // QDRIVERINTERFACESIM_H
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not really understand what you mean by *first* and *second*. Does this source code go all into one single module/dll/exe? Or is there an intended hierarchy?

There are a few (more general) suggestions I can give:

- **avoid include-file name clashes**

  I would change the name of your header `"types.h"` into something like `"legotron_driver_types.h"` because there are thousands of software environments and libraries that also have a header called `"types.h"`. You want to avoid these name clashes.
- **make your interface symmetric**

  There are `sendData()` functions for sending data. Are there only call-back functions for recieving available? I see a `getRouteTable()` function while there is no `setRouteTable()` function. You should have the following functions as well:

  ```
  disconnectFromHardware();
  receiveData();
  receiveDataWithAck();
  receiveDataWithAckBlocked();
  setRouteTable();
  removeAutoRoute();
  ```

  Having the interface completely symmetric can divide your problem up into more manageable chunks.
- **divide the interface into "levels"**

  You may also want to divide the interface into high-level, middle-level and low-level functions. For example the `sendData(); receiveData();` function pair may be considered low-level. While the `sendDataWithAck(); receiveDataWithAck();` may be considered a higher level. This allows you to test the levels independently and to first build the lower level where you can build on higher levels later.
- **use `const` keyword to specify input arguments**

  I'm not a big fan of [name pre-fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228161/why-use-prefixes-on-member-variables-in-c-classes) however, you have an interesting way of using them in the type definitions. But you could qualify the functions arguments that are not changed by the function with `const`. This can effectively specify which arguments are input-only and which have output:

  ```
   sendDataWithAck(dev_addr_t const dev,    // "in" device
                   com_t const com,         // "in" com port ?
                   pdata_t const pdata,     // "in" pointer to data
                   data_sz_t const data_sz, // "in" data size
                   ack_id_t *p_ack_id);     // "out" ack ID
  ```
- **indicate error**

  Most of your functions have int as a return value. I assume that this will be an error code. Declare a type for this:

  ```
  enum class retCode {
      NO_ERROR = 0,
      SYNTAX_ERROR,
      OTHER_ERROR,
      INTERFACE_ERROR = 400,
      CANNOT_CREATE_INTERFACE_ERROR
  };
  ```
- **be clear about C/C++ borders**

  You mention in the intro text something about *"extern "C" SHARED" wrappers*. Where exactly is your border from C to C++? Do you really **need to fall back** to C? I see that your member functions mostly use C-Style types. Where is the exact border where you jump from C to C++? In some cases, this may be the only way to do it, but try to use "C++ thinking" whenever you can. It will simplify your code and increase readability.

  Have a look at the defintition of `getRouteTable()`:

  ```
  virtual int getRouteTable(dev_addr_t dev, 
                            route_t route_table[1], 
                            rows_cnt_t *prow_count) = 0;
  ```

  What is the second argument supposed to pass?
- **in C++ use references when you can**

  The `sendData()` function could look like this in more C++ style:

  ```
  class Device;     // declaration of device class
  class Port;       // declaration of com port class
  class DataBlock;

  virtual retCode sendData(  Device const & dev,
                             Port const & com,
                             DataBlock const & pdata,
                             size_t const & data_sz   );
  ```